# A better way of enforcing a list

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Please consider the follow rule:

```
"list" : {
    "$item" : {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['field1', 'field2'])",
            "field1" : {
                ".validate": newData.isString()
            },
            "field2" : {
                ".validate": newData.isString()
            },
            "$other" : {
                ".validate": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should only allow you to build a list of objects of a certain type. However, there's nothing to prevent the following:

```
{
    "list" : "i've been hacked"
}
```

Only thing I've been able to come up with is to add this to the "list" rules:

```
".validate": "!newData.isString() && !newData.isNumber() && !newData.isBoolean()"
```

.. which is a bit clunky. Is there a better to enforce this or is my whole approach just wrong-headed?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add .write: false to the list itself, and only enable it on the $item. This way, you can't write to list without validating $item rule.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @cwehrung's answer:

```js
"list": {
  ".write": false,
  "$item": {
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['field1', 'field2'])",
    "field1": {
      ".write": "newData.isString()"
    },
    "field2": {
      ".write": "newData.isString()"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This method works fine for a top level list and I will use it - however for sub-lists ".write" will already be set true at a higher point in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
"list": {
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()",
    ...
}
```